# Three select dropdown for school year that hides previous years

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5.1

How to hide years in select dropdown if not needed.  I have 3 select dropdown for school year using php code snippet.  Example in the first dropdown:

```
    2016-2017
    2015-2016
    2014-2015
    2013-2014
    2012-2013
    2011-2012

    If i select 2012-2013, the 2nd dropdown should display:
    2016-2017
    2015-2016
    2014-2015
    2013-2014
   If i select 2014-2015, the 3rd dropdown should display:
    2016-2017
    2015-2016
```

> Is there a possible way using php code snippet alone or do i have
>   to use javascript?
>       The problem is, I'd tried my code in php but no luck and the more if i use javascript since I'm not get used of it.Hope anyone could
>   help me or give me a light on doing the next step base on my present
>   code.
>
> Here is my code:

```
<label class="control-label">SY 1:</label> 
    <select class="form-control" name="scholar_secondary_school_year" id="test" onchange="educSec(this)">
               <?php 
                $null = 'null';
                $choose = 'Choose SY';
                $Present = 'Present';
          echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
          echo '<option value='.$Present.'>' .$Present.'</option>';
                  for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                     $x = $i +1;
                     $y = $i;
       echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                   }?>
    </select>

    <label class="control-label">SY 2:</label> 
    <select class="form-control" name="scholar_secondary_school_year" id="test" onchange="educSec(this)">
               <?php 
                $null = 'null';
                $choose = 'Choose SY';
                $Present = 'Present';
          echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
          echo '<option value='.$Present.'>' .$Present.'</option>';
                  for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                     $x = $i +1;
                     $y = $i;
       echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                   }?>
    </select>

    <label class="control-label">SY 3:</label> 
    <select class="form-control" name="scholar_secondary_school_year" id="test" onchange="educSec(this)">
               <?php 
                $null = 'null';
                $choose = 'Choose SY';
                $Present = 'Present';
          echo '<option value='.$null.'>' .$choose.'</option>';
          echo '<option value='.$Present.'>' .$Present.'</option>';
                  for($i=date('Y');  $i > date('Y')-30; $i--){

                     $x = $i +1;
                     $y = $i;
       echo '<option value='.$y.'-'.$x.'>'.$y.'-'.$x.'</option>';
                   }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: You need javascript for this; even the most ugly solution would need it to submit the form on change of a select. The nicest solution would be to use only javascript.

Comment: @jeroen - Thank you for that info Sir.